# What is a good live request monitor for Apache httpd?

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, httpd, requests

I have used SeeFusion to monitor ColdFusion requests.  Is there a similar tool that would allow me to monitor Apache httpd requests in real time?  We have a server that was fast and responsive for months, but suddenly today, it is using 80% cpu instead of 1%, I have no idea where to start to figure out what is bogging it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Apache's [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apachetop to see how many requests apache is handling in real time (if you have access logs), also you can use something like awstats, cacti (but its not quite real time)

Comment: There's a command called topto?  or did you mean top to.  When I use top, doesn't tell me the URI I'd need to determine where the problem is.

Comment: I just corrected typo .... the command is apachetop

Comment: My CentOS does not have apachetop, which package do I install to get it?